# (Uncaught ReferenceError: defaultInteractions is not defined) How Can I Add "Translate Features" To My Openlayers6 Project In Asp.Net Core5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm new to Openlayers. While I was using Node.js, my codes were working fine. But I ran into some problems when I switched to Asp.Net Core.

I learned that when calling modules to use them in Asp.Net Core I need to add some prefixes to their heads.

For example to be able to use the "Map" module:

```
const map = new ol.Map({ });
```

But I don't know what prefix I should add before **"defaultInteractions()"** in this line

```
interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([select, translate]),
```

Here is my **Map** code snippet

```
const map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([select, translate]),
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                url: 'https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png',
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: extent,
            }),
        }),
        rasterLayer, vectorLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 8,
    }),
});
```

When I ctrl + left click on **defaultInteraction()**, the **ol.interaction.js page** opens,

When I ctrl + left click on **extend([select, translate])** the **ol.Collection.js page** opens.

But both are not working.

[**Here is the error i got**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRRed.png)

**Thanks in advance and have a good day** <(^.^)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[solved]**
I changed the line to:

```
interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, translate]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

Using `ol.interaction.defaults.defaults().extend()`

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults.defaults().extend([select, translate]),
    // interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, translate]), // wrong

...
})
```